# How do I make my phone sync to UTC, not GPS time?

Tags: clock, date-and-time

I recently discovered that my phone's time was 17 seconds fast.  After some digging, I discovered that GPS time is 17 seconds ahead of UTC, due to not having leap seconds.

In my phone, I have selected the time to be set automatically via "Use network provided values".  But when I compare the local time to GPS time (via a logger application which logs both GPS and local time simultaneously) I see that they are identical, suggesting that it is syncing to GPS time, not UTC time.

How can I keep my phone synchronized to UTC time, not GPS time?